# rJava installation cant find libjvm.so

Tags: java, r, rjava

Not sure why rJava does not install properly.

I try pinnint the libpath but it is still not working..?

```
.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server") )


ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-76:/$ ls -al /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16925812 Jun 30 05:53 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
```

error....

```
> library(rJava)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo R CMD javareconf` from the command line and then reinstall `rJava`?

Comment: Yes!!!it works now Thanks!